# Crash marshalling string to .NET

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am using .NET Core 2.2 to call a native C library via P/Invoke. Most methods take simple int arguments and return int values, and these are all working OK. A few methods take `wchar_t*` arguments, and these are working as well, as long as I decorate those args with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`.

However, I have one function with a C signature like:

```c
wchar_t * GetFormatDesc(int id1, int id2, int index, int options)
```

I call it from C# with this definition:

```cs
[DllImport("the.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string GetFormatDesc(int id1, int id2, int index, int options);
```

When I call this method from .NET, the process terminates immediately with a message like `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 2016) exited with code -1073740940.`. I assume there is an access violation happening. If instead I have that method return an `IntPtr` it appears to succeed, and I can use the following unsafe code to read a very standard looking nul-terminated ANSI string from it:

```cs
IntPtr desc = Wrapper.GetFormatDesc(1234, 1, 1, 0);

unsafe
{
    int i = 0;
    var l = new StringBuilder();
    var c = (char*)desc;
    while (*c != '\0')
    {
        l.Append(*c);
        i++;
        c = (char*)desc + i;
    }
}
```

I've tried marshalling as both `LPStr` and `LPWStr`, and setting `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi`, but it still crashes. The code above does work, but it requires building with `/unsafe`, and just plain reeks. I don't have any access to the source for the C library; the definition above is everything I know about it. How can I marshall this string in a safe/standard way?

**edit**

This is not a memory leak or inability to release memory.

As it turns out, the C library just doesn't follow consistent standards for terminating strings, so the "normal" string marshal will fail inconsistently. Elsewhere in the documentation I finally found a separate method which returns the length of the last string/array returned, and this must be used to manually `Marshal.Copy` the values into managed memory.

Comment: It's more than just the lack of a null terminator. You also face the issue that the marshaler assumes that the memory was allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc.

Comment: Who knows, they may have? It's 3rd party with atrocious docs, so I have no idea how it's allocating on the native side. Either way, `Marshal.Copy` with size retrieved from this second method is working reliably now.

Comment: No. The pinvoke marshaler of .net assumes that the memory was allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc. And hence calls CoTaskMemFree on the pointer that was returned. Almost certainly it was not. Also, use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi if you want to unmarshal a C string. This sort of information can be found with more thorough websearch.